# Using pony gem and ckeditor in my rails 3 application to send bulk mailing

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ckeditor, pony

I am using ckeditor im my application for bulk mailing using pony gem mail is getting sent but I have a couple of problems:

1. Some tags are also delivered in mail.
2. If I apply effects to text like bold, italic, underline etc are visible in mail
3. Image is not visible instead of that {"body"=>" is visible.

Following is the code...

1. My pony mail function...

> ```
> params[:l].each do |single_email|
>         p single_email
>         Pony.mail(:to => single_email, :from => 'example@example.co.in', :subject => @bmail.subject, 
>       :headers => { "Content-Type" => "text/html"}, :body => @bmail.body, :via => :smtp, :via_options => { 
>       :address => "smtp.gmail.com", 
>       :port => 587, 
>       :domain => 'example.co.in', 
>       :user_name => 'example@example.co.in', 
>       :password => 'paswd', 
>       :authentication => 'plain', 
>       :enable_starttls_auto => true 
> })    end
> ```

1. Call to ckeditor

> ```
> %br = cktext_area :body, :body, :ckeditor => {:uiColor => "#AADC6E", :toolbar => "mini"} 
> %br
> ```

Please help me to deliver perfect mail with image and stuffs, plz help me as soon as possible.
Thanz in advance.

Comment: Plz help me as soon as possible... Thankz

Answer (score 0):

try :html_body => @bmail.body

http://rubydoc.info/gems/pony/1.4.1/frames